# WooCommerce: How to remove tax in coupon discount?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any ideas how to remove the coupon discount tax?

Right now, all products where deducted from 12% tax. When adding a coupon for discount, it has also a 12% tax deduction?

Any way to remove the coupon discount tax?

Thanks

Comment: Usually, the tax is only on the total amount to be paid. So tax deduction un this case is ok, isn't?

Comment: My problem is, I have $50 discount coupon but it breaks down as

Discount: $44.64         Tax: $5.35

Is there a way to display just 
Discount: $50
?

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand. so the only problem is the display, not the fact that part of the discount is tax, right? I mean you don't want to make discount of $50 before the tax deduction.

Comment: Yes. I don't have problems how woocommerce compute it. Just the display. I dont want to display $44.64. I want it to be $50. Because right now its very confusing to the customers who received the invoice. They put $50 coupon discount, and in the invoice they received, it display Discount: $44.64. They don't know that the rest of the discount which is $5.36 is already deducted to the VAT.